# Sonic firewall configuration with huawei router

Tags: networking, router, firewall, nat

My question is that I want to configure my sonic firewall device with my huawei router . The huawei router is connected with fiber optic having external ip address 18x.xxx.xxx.xxx subnet mask :255.255.255.0 static IP address from ISP.
While the router has its own dhcp server and assigning Ip's in local subnet . 
Is it possible to configure sonic firewall to connect with my router using router's external IP address which is 18x.xxx.xxx.xxx subnet mask :255.255.255.0 ?

As I have seen in the router WAN's status and it says IP acquisition =DHCP.

I have configured my sonic firewall with dhcp wan and its been assigned the IP address automatically from DHCP of router .

I have added that IP address in huawei DMZ zone but still once I try to connect with the public IP address("18x.xxx.xxx.xxx" static IP of my router interface)

to access sonic firewall its unaccessible and it keeps on going to the interface of my router login page.

I have also configured access rules and Nat rules in the sonic firewall.

Comment: Is the Huawei a true router (ethernet in/out) or is it an ONT (Optical Network Termination) router? Either way, this will likely require coordination with your ISP to get a public IP address for your Sonicwall router. If it is just an Ethernet interface, you should be able to connect it directly to the ISP hand-off point and get an IP address although they may have to setup their equipment to allow your Sonicwall's MAC address to connect. I think you are largely overthinking the setup here, or do not understand the basics of networks, routers, and IP addressing (I mean no offense).

Comment: I think you didnt properly follow my question . As huawei router is connected with optic fiber and in result assigned with the static IP address by ISP.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know... So you the public IP address is assigned to the Huawei router, so to get it to "pass-though" the device, you will need to contact your ISP to put your router in bridge mode and allow your Sonicwall's IP MAC address to obtain an IP address or use a 1:1 NAT translation.

Comment: Be aware that in some parts of the world, for residential service you are behind a enterprise grade NAT, and your public IP address is shared... To get "your own" public IP address you must pay for a commercial service account. I can't tell you if this applies to your situation or not, as it can vary by country and ISP and I don't know the policies of all ISP's in the world. Basically though, to make it work you likely need to contact your ISP and get them to adjust their equipment to allow it to connect that way.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can you please explain 1:1 NAT ?

Comment: 1:1 NAT is where you have a public IP address that is essentially mapped to an internal IP address... For example, if a request comes in on port 443/TCP to the router, it will be forwarded on the same port to a specific internal IP address. Most commercial grade routers support this, I can't say if your router does or not, but it would likely have an entry in the same area as port forwarding or DMZ

Comment: alright . Yes my router has DMZ option. So , if I add my internal IP to DMZ its ok?? Do I require port forward as DMZ is already public .